# Por que dá erro quando tento atribuir um valor na variável dentro de um operador condicional?

Tags: c, variáveis, operadores

Eu tenho o seguinte código que deve receber 4 números e dizer qual deles é o maior.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max_of_four(int x, int z, int y, int w);

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);

    return 0;
}


int max_of_four(int x, int z, int y, int w){
    int max1, max2;

    x > z ? max1 = x : max1 == z;
    y > w ? max2 = y : max2 == w;


    return max1 > max2 ? max1: max2;
}
```

A minha dúvida está na função `max_of_four`. Eu comparo dois números duas vezes e o maior deve ser atribuído à sua respectiva variável. Na parte do `else` `(... : max1 == z; / ... : max2 == w;)` em vez de `==` deveria ser `=`, porém se eu colocar o `=` o código dá o erro:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Por outro lado, se eu deixo o `==` o código não roda direito, não imprimindo o valor mais alto caso ele esteja na segunda ou quarta posição.

Eu sei que poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
 int max1 = x > z ? x : z;
 int max2 = y > w ? y : w;
```

Porém gostaria de saber se meu código é incorrigível ou se estou deixando algo passar.

Comment: Não tem muito sentido este == pois o resultado será verdadeiro ou falso e não uma atribuição. O correto é o que você colocou no final.

Comment: Função foi criada depois. Eu já tive esse problema. Sempre deixe main nas ultimas linhas

Comment: Tente: (x > z) ? (max1 = x) : (max1 = z); ,que aqui funcionou, pois você especifica sem dúvidas quais são as expressões.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper A função está no final, porém eu a declarei no topo antes da função principal. A dica de colocar entre parênteses os termos funcionou e o Luiz Augusto explicou direitinho o que acontece. Muito obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifiquei seu código com operador ternário e não compila, porém usando a estrutura de seleção `if/else` o mesmo compila.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max_of_four(int x, int z, int y, int w);




int max_of_four(int x, int z, int y, int w){
    int max1, max2;

    if (x > z) 
    max1 = x;
    else
    max1 = z;

    if (y > w)
     max2 = y;
     else
      max2 = w;


    return (max1 > max2 ? max1 : max2);
}
int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);

    return 0;
}
```

Colocando a busca no google: *lvalue required as left operand of assignment ternary operator*
Encontro as seguintes perguntas:

1. [“lvalue required as left operand of assignment” error - ternary
   operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38949499/lvalue-required-as-left-operand-of-assignment-error-ternary-operator?rq=1)
2. [Error: lvalue required in this simple C code? (Ternary with
   assignment?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966299/error-lvalue-required-in-this-simple-c-code-ternary-with-assignment)

Traduzindo, via google translate, a [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38950524/10301489):

Na linguagem C, a gramática e a semântica do operador condicional são diferentes de C ++. Seu código seria compilado em C ++, já que em C ++ a expressão

```
 <condition> ? a = b : c = d
```

seria analisado como

```
 <condition> ? (a = b) : (c = d)
```

**Porém em C**, a mesma expressão é analisada como

```
 (<condition> ? (a = b) : c) = d
```

que é uma história completamente diferente. O resultado de `?:` em C nunca é um `lvalue`, e é por isso que a última análise não é compilada.

Answer (score 5):

Você consegue fazer o que deseja, só a sintaxe estava um pouco errada, veja só que dá pra ser até mais simples:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max_of_four(int x, int z, int y, int w) {
    int max1 = x > z ? x : z;
    int max2 = y > w ? y : w;
    return max1 > max2 ? max1 : max2;
}

int main() {
    int a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
    printf("%d", ans);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QWfeLD). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/AssignInConditional). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/AssignInConditional.c).

Ah, mas você quer fazer de outro jeito, então sim, seu código é incorrigível. Seu gosto não pode se sobrepor ao mais correto.

Você está misturando *statement* com expressão. O operador condicional existe para simplificar quando você tem expressões. Você está querendo transformar um código de *statement* em expressão e isto é errado, mesmo que funcione. Você está tornando o código mais ilegível, então não faça, simples assim.

Uma atribuição gera um efeito colateral e este tipo de cóisa é o que mais causa *bugs*, por isso deve estar muito visível, deve ser  no início da linha pra ficar óbvio. Você está usando um operador para substituir uma construção de linguagem e "encurtar", isso não é legal. Por que não usar o operador do jeito certo de forma que encurta mais ainda?

Comment: Entendi. Então eu devo apenas usar um Operador Ternário quando eu quiser atribuir um valor a uma variável sob uma condição? Achei que era uma forma mais curta de escrever, não sabia que tinha certas condições sintáticas para o Op. Ternário. Muito obrigado pela correção teórica!